# Unable to login using the Active Directory Credentials to an Amazon Linux server

Tags: active-directory, amazon-linux

I have provisioned a new Amazon Linux server in AWS environment and joined the server to the domain. I can see the Linux machine in the AD but cannot able to login using the AD credentials. However, I have tried to use the AD credentials but the following error has been encountered:

**No Supported Authentication Methods Available (Server Sent: Public Key)**

Could someone look at this and provide the resolution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Amazon Linux, before you join the server to Active Directory make sure the **password authentication** attribute is set to **true** and **AllowUsers** string is added in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.

Once added the required parameters, join the server to Active Directory and once joined, you can login directly with your AD credentials